# mixing container and container-fluid using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show my site of fixed for all xs, sm and md screens but for lg screens I want my site fluid. From bootstrap grid ssytem I found that either I can use .container class for fixed width or .container-fluid for fluid. So how can I target different container for different screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS media query to specify a specific (fixed) width on the smallest screens like this. For Bootstrap the threshold for `xs` is 768 pixels..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width:760px; /* set fixed width */
  }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/131026